# Xcode: Set exception breakpoint on certain exception

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I am watching this very helpful talk on debugging Unity applications:
https://youtu.be/s7Ple1G83jc?si=akMsvWwUo2kCWex7&t=828

At 13:55 they show how to debug C++ exceptions by defining an exception breakpoint on a certain exception type in Xcode.

However, when I try to do the same in Xcode 15, the "named" field is missing in the Exception Breakpoint dialog. Without it, my app breaks on every Unity gameloop frame, for whatever reason, so I definitely need this restriction to get to the actual root cause I am looking for.

Is there a way to set a specific Exception type in newer versions of Xcode?